# How to create Procs with variable arguments in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I want to pass arguments to a Proc like using [splat](http://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/splats_and_tuples.html), but it returns an error `wrong number of block arguments (1 for 0)`

```
$callbacks = {} of String => Array(->)

def add_callback(event, &block)
  begin
    $callbacks[event.to_s] << block
  rescue
    $callbacks[event.to_s] = [block]
  end
end

add_callback(:event) do |arg|
  puts "event!"
end

$callbacks["event"].first.call
```

`Error in line 11: wrong number of block arguments (1 for 0)` http://carc.in/#/r/7gw

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the argument list everywhere.

```
class EventManager
  def initialize
    @callbacks = Hash(String, Array(String ->)).new {|h, k| h[k] = [] of String -> }
  end

  def add(event, &callback : String ->)
    @callbacks[event] << callback
  end

  def fire(event, argument : String)
    @callbacks[event].each &.call(argument)
  end
end

callbacks = EventManager.new
callbacks.add("foo") do |argument|
  puts "Got #{argument}"
end
callbacks.add("bar") do
  puts "I was called"
end
callbacks.fire "foo", "Ping"
callbacks.fire "bar", "Pong"
```

Comment: Not fully, no. Crystal needs to know the argument list and supporting many different ones in the same collection will become fairly ugly to manage pretty soon. As I've shown it's however possible to omit block arguments you don't need.

Comment: I understand... and then I tried to make this with Hash and I think I don't understand how it works yet http://carc.in/#/r/7hk

Comment: If you hash doesn't interfere to the right type, you need to be a bit more explicit http://carc.in/#/r/7hm